# MoPub Android HttpResponse cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android, mopub

I'm using mopub sdk 4.8.0. I included the following libraries, as it says in [documentation](https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk):

```
android-support-v4.jar,
android-support-annotations.jar,
android-support-v7-recyclerview.jar,
mopub-volley-1.1.0.jar
```

But when I build the project, following errors are written to Logcat:

> The type org.apache.http.HttpResponse cannot be resolved. It is
>   indirectly referenced from required .class
>   files RequestQueueHttpStack.java  /mopub-sdk/src/com/mopub/network    line
>   1 Cannot find the class file for org.apache.http.HttpResponse.

What libraries do I need to add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**org.apache.http** has been deprecated for a while now and since API Level 23 (Android 6.0) it's not among Androids default dependencies anymore.

It's still available but you need to add the dependency to your Apps **build.grandle** file like so:

```
android {

    ....

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

some more infos about it can be found here: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client